# How does c++ for loop change to scheme

Tags: c++, scheme

*c++*

```
int loop(int x, int y, int z) {
     int result = 0;
     for ( int i = x; i < y; i+=z ) { result += i; }
     return result; }
```

*Just i try that by scheme*

```
(letrec ((my-loop (lambda (a b c)
  (begin
    (let ((i a) (s 0))
    (if (< i b)
          (set! s (+ s i)) s))))))(my-loop (+ a c) b c))
```

please write correct code of scheme....

Comment: Scheme is a recursive lenguaje, try not to use `set`, a `let loop` will help you to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you...but my fixed code is error continuous. I don't know how to fix. help me

Comment: you don't need `set!` or `let` or `letrec`. simply use recursion. you just need 1) a recursive step 2) a base case.

Comment: watch the classic SICP lectures: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Op3QLzMgSY&list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46

Comment: I want to use let but I don't know well about method of using let. So please make a scheme code to above c++ code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a straightforward translation to a `do` loop:

```
(define (foo x y z)
  (do ((result 0 (+ result i))
       (i x (+ i z)))
      ((>= i y) result)))
```

However, many Schemers find `do` loops to be distasteful. So here's an identical loop that uses named `let`, which is in fact what the `do` is likely to expand to:

```
(define (foo x y z)
  (let loop ((result 0)
             (i x))
    (if (>= i y)
        result
        (loop (+ result i) (+ i z)))))
```

which is likely to expand to:

```
(define (foo x y z)
  ((rec (loop result i)
     (if (>= i y)
         result
         (loop (+ result i) (+ i z))))
   0 x))
```

which then expands to:

```
(define (foo x y z)
  ((letrec ((loop (lambda (result i)
                    (if (>= i y)
                        result
                        (loop (+ result i) (+ i z))))))
     loop)
   0 x))
```

Yay macros! Choose the version you like best; most Schemers I know prefer the second one.

Comment: What is `rec`? Is it like `fix` or `Y`? Where can I see its definition? Is it standardized?.... ....found it! SRFI-31. :)