# Scheme self-reference lambda macro

Tags: macros, lambda, scheme

```
(define-macro slambda
  (lambda (args body)
    `(let ((self (lambda ,args ,body)))
        self)))
```

Hello, I have a "problem" with this macro for self-referencing lambda.. It works, but fails when I want to refer to "self" from outside.. meaning that first aplication works, second doesn't

1. ((slambda (x) (+ x 1)) 10)
2. ((slambda () self))

Comment: Thank you for that question! Thanks to you I found an answer to my own question with simple searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **quote** the *lambda-part* where you quasiqute so it can be assigned to *self*.

```
(define-macro slambda
  (lambda (arg1 . arg2)
    `(let ((self '(slambda ,arg1 ,@arg2)))
       (lambda ,arg1 ,@arg2))))
```

The dot and *unquote-splicing* is needed there if you want to use it with more than one argument.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would work better you replaced `let` for `letrec` like this:

```
(define-macro slambda
  (lambda (args body)
    `(letrec ((self (lambda ,args ,body)))
        self)))
```

In Scheme you have lexical scope and `self` is not in effect until the body of the `let`. The procedure called `self` in the body of the let is not defined by that name inside itself. It's perhaps easier to see if you desugar `let`:

```
((lambda (self) ...)
 (lambda () self)) ; self referenced outside procedure that defines it
```

Notice that `define-macro` isn't a standard scheme syntax so you should have specified which implementation you are using. Luckily this problem had nothing to do with macros.

Comment: Yep, I switched it to letrec and some cases started working, but I stopped at this application ((slambda () (slambda () self) self)) .. It should work tho I guess

Comment: @Poody Your `slambda` macro doesn't correctly handle more than one body form, which is the problem you're running into.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young So I need to go deeper?

Comment: @Poody You need to make your macro take multiple arguments for the body. Though, I still believe that `define-macro` is the wrong way to solve this. If you're using Racket, you can just use my answer. If you're using a different implementation, you'd be better off just using [`rec`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html).

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young I read your answer and I didn't really understood it.. I did some basics with define-syntax, but you got .. really.. into it

Comment: I suggest you try to expand it by hand to ensure it works as you expect. With nesting the inner `self` is not the same as the outer.

Comment: @Poody Then just use `rec`, and forget about trying to write an anaphoric macro (and forget about my answer). Your brain will thank you for your assistance in stopping its pain. :-) Trust me, `rec` is the standard way to write a self-referencing procedure.

Comment: @Poody I agree with Chris except the way you are using it it might be you can use named `let` instead.

Comment: @Sylwester I agree with the use of named `let`, because it expands to `rec` anyway. :-) I wrote a blog post about this: http://dyscour.se/post/58639636506/named-let

Comment: @Poody Further to Sylwester's recommendation for named `let` (which I agree is potentially a good way to solve your problem), here's an example of the correspondence between named `let` and `rec`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22870415/13

Comment: @Poody Try to figure out what your expanded code should look like. When people ask questions about writing macros, I always ask them what their "before and after" is. :-)

Comment: @Poody I don't know what implementation you are using so I cannot check, but `((slambda () (slambda () self) self))` would return the same as `(slambda () self)` since it would have overshadowed the previous `self`

Comment: ((slambda () (slambda () self) self)) should return (slambda () (slambda () self) self) .. probably

Comment: @Poody `((slambda () (slambda () self) self))` won't turn into ` (slambda () (slambda () self) self)` but the same as `(slambda () self)`. `self` is overshadowed in the inner `slambda` so it won't reference to the outer one.  DrRacket 3.7.2 is ancient. Version 6.0 was released this week so consider upgrading.

Comment: @Sylwester I don't know about Poody's macro, but my macro does return the outer function. Why? Because the inner one is not bound or returned anywhere, so it's thrown away. Try this (tested on Racket 6.0): `(let ((foo (slambda () (slambda () self) self))) (eq? foo ((((((foo))))))))`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scheme you might be better off using standard define-syntax rather than the not-always-supported define-macro.  With define-syntax, you have to use datum->syntax to get the macro to act unhygienically and inject the name 'self' into the output syntax.  This is your code translated to define-syntax, as tested with guile:

```
(define-syntax slambda
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
      [(slambda formals body0 body1 ...)
       (with-syntax ([self (datum->syntax #'slambda 'self)])
                    #'(letrec ([self (lambda formals body0 body1 ...)])
                        self))])))
```

Comment: this looks much cleaner than I had expected - thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Sylwester's answer is correct, but I wanted to make a bigger point: unless your Scheme implementation doesn't provide a hygienic procedural macro system, there is no good reason to use `define-macro`.

For anaphoric macros, such as the one you want to write, it's best to use syntax parameters, if you're using a Scheme implementation that supports it, such as Racket or Guile. Here's a Racket example:

```
#lang racket
(provide slambda self)
(require racket/stxparam srfi/31)

(define-syntax-parameter self
  (lambda (stx)
    (raise-syntax-error 'self "Can only be used inside slambda")))

(define-syntax slambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ params body ...)
     (rec (ohai . params)
       (syntax-parameterize ((self (make-rename-transformer #'ohai)))
         body ...)))))
```

---

Of course, as you can see in my example, I used [`rec`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html). In the general case where you want to make self-referential procedures, it's best to use `rec` for that; you simply specify the name you want to refer to the procedure by (rather than using a hardcoded `self`). Since `rec` is not anaphoric, its definition is much simpler:

```
(define-syntax rec
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (id . params) body ...)
     (rec id (lambda params body ...)))
    ((_ id value)
     (letrec ((id value)) id))))
```

You would use it like this (in this case, I use `recur` as the self-reference; of course, you can choose any name you like):

```
(define nested-length
  (rec (recur x)
    (cond ((null? x) 0)
          ((pair? x) (+ (recur (car x)) (recur (cdr x))))
          (else 1))))
```